# QGIS "difference" tool - "feature has invalid geometry" - returns empty layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector

[image]

I am trying to return the areas of the red polygon that fall outside of the orange polygon, using the difference tool.

Both are vector layers I created by drawing around a georeferenced map. Their attribute tables only contain their area, shown below.

When I run the difference tool, it returns "Feature has invalid geography", and the resulting layer is empty and does not appear on my map.

Comment: If you're sure the CRS are the same, there's a vertical line on top of the left orange area that might be source of "invalid geometry"?

Comment: Yeah thats a result of a misclick when drawing the polygon - is there any way to remove it without redrawing the whole polygon?

Comment: But also I get the same results when using a polygon that overlaps only the bottom part of the red polygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix geometries:**
(Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Fix geometries)

> This algorithm attempts to create a valid
> representation of a given invalid geometry without losing any of the
> input vertices. Already-valid geometries are returned without further
> intervention.

Then try Difference